# IntelliJ Build Artifact with gradle filter resource during ProcessResources

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, war

**Question:** 
How do we make IntelliJ Build artifact replace our token strings from our processResources Gradle task. I would like to avoid manual configuration of IntelliJ, which I think its 'ant preprocess' would be. I would like the configuration to just be in a Gradle script.

**Our environment:**

We use Gradle to build our war containers, and IntelliJ as IDE. During development we deploy in exploded Artifacts in IntelliJ using its 'Build Artifact'. Our Gradle process-resources filters a few log4j.xml files and similar using ant ReplaceToken like this

```
processResources {
        filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [VERSION_TOKEN: version])
}
```

We use IntelliJ's import Gradle modules, and it creates 'Web Gradle' facet resource artifacts of type 'Web. When we let Intellij build our artifacts and deploy exploded wars in development. IntelliJ's build artifact executes the filter token replacement as defined in process resources.

However this processResources definition hits all files, and it ruins my PNG files.

The following still works in Gradle, but now IntelliJs build Artifact does not substitute the tokens

```
processResources {
    filesMatching('**/log4j2.xml') {
        filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [VERSION_TOKEN: version])
    }
}
```

Likewise if I do substitution in `doFirst{}` or do a `eachFile { copyDetails -> if (copyDetails.path == 'log4j2.xml') { filter... } }}`.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I am facing this exact issue....